# Taking out numeric data and multiply one and add another from a string

Tags: r

I need to get the 2 or more numbers out of a string when there are letters behind them, then would need to multiply the first number by 8 and add the second to give 1 number in a new column. I have got as far as getting the 2 numbers out but, can't figure out how I would then do the sum for both numbers

Data looks like
2m6f
1m7f

```
x <- GBF$distance
x_numbers <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x))
```

Can get

2 6
1 7

Need to get

Distf

22
15

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming the input x shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, replace non-digits with space and read using read.table giving a data frame whose columns are numeric.  Then convert that to a matrix and matrix multiply it by the indicated vector giving the one column matrix shown. No packages are used.

```
as.matrix(read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", x))) %*% c(8, 1)
##      [,1]
## [1,]   22
## [2,]   15
```

**1a)** If the non-digits were always m and f (male and female?) then we can eliminate the gsub simplifying it to this:

```
as.matrix(read.table(text = x, sep = "m", comment = "f")) %*% c(8, 1)
##      [,1]
## [1,]   22
## [2,]   15
```

**2)** If the question had intended that the starting point be x_numbers then convert each element of it into a numeric vector giving a numeric matrix and cross product that with the indicated vector. Again, no packages are used.

```
crossprod(sapply(x_numbers, as.numeric), c(8, 1))
##      [,1]
## [1,]   22
## [2,]   15
```

### Note

```
x <- c("2m6f", "1m7f")
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to have worked now

Comment: @Ez123 [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have just noticed at this will not work in all cases as some would only have a 5f in the column, so this would be just need 5, is there a way that it can use a something like a translate/IF statement?

Comment: Paste `0m` onto the front of any element that has no m converting it to the form described in the question.  For example `x <- c("2m6f", "1m7f", "5f"); m <- grepl("m", x); x[!m] <- paste0("0m", x[!m])`

Comment: I do have 1 other type of occurrence in the data  2m4Â½f, this is a distance data so 2miles 4furlong and 110yds in this case, would this be adding, so would an Ifelse be better used or is there a way to include this on the above, I have tried adding the character to this but keep getting an error

Comment: You will have to explain how those characters imply 110 yards.  I only see 2 and 4 as digits plus m and f and some junk.

Comment: The, Â½f, breaks down as "and 1/2f" which is 110 yards, so the 2m4Â½f, is 2m4fand 110yds. There are other distances in this with 7Â½f, which are 7f and 110 yds, with the above I can get the 0m in so it's nearly there.

Comment: Add the vector `a * grepl("Â½", x)` to the answer where `a` is the amount you want to add if Â½ is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Extract all numeric values into a list and then sapply a function across the list which does the numerical calculations needed:

```
library(stringr)
x = c("2m6f", "1m7f")
sapply(str_extract_all(x, "[:digit:]"), 
    function(x) (as.numeric(x[1]) * 8) + as.numeric(x[2])
    )
```

```
[1] 22 15
```